# Does messageRule re-evaluates after message changed by Microsoft Graph API call?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I would like to create a `MessageRule` that will move a certain email to a given folder by using a `messageRulePredicates` of type `headerContains`.

That means, that if a message has some string in it's headers then I want to messageRule to move this message to some folder.

My questions are:

1. Will this re-evaluates after a header has been manually changed (through API), i.e. if I'll make the call to update message through the Graph API, and change the headers so it will now contain the string, then will the rule detect the change and move the message? or is it only evaluates once when the message arrives to the inbox?
2. I know I have an API to directly move an email that I can use, thing is, sometimes the change doesn't take effect on the Outlook desktop client, so was wondering if by using messageRule can help re-assure that mail actually move in the user client.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reaching out. To my knowledge, it is not currently possible to update the `internetMessageHeaders` via Graph API, see [update message documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). I tested this in Graph Explorer and can confirm. This rule seems to be evaluated only when the message hits the inbox.

Let me know whether this helps and if you have further questions,